# When using tensorflow distributed, the memory of four GPUs suddenly filled up when sever.join ()

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

I ran the model on a four-way GTX1070 in Ubuntu, but when I started the terminal running the program, when I type python ... py --job_name = "ps" --task_index = 0, the four GPUs look Sub-layer was full, and I have not opened a new terminal to run the worker, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is how Tensorflow works. When it starts with GPU, it allocate almost all the memory.

One small thing you could try is to limit the portion of GPU allocation:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5)
sess = tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options = gpu_options))
```

But it controls all GPUs memories so you cannot be sure how the memory will be split (If you put 0.25, it could take all the memory on 1 GPU and 0 on other, or another configuration).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In fact, I tried this method, but still take up all the memory, I do not know why, is it because I use Supervisor, and then use sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session (server.target, config = sess_config) reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem recently, it might be because you used `server = tf.train.Server(...)` in your code and didn't pass a config argument, 
so TF default took all the memory of all your GPU, thus there's no memory left for the worker task.

The solution might be:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5)
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options = gpu_options)
server = tf.train.Server(..., config=config)
```

Anyway, it worked for me, hope that helps you.